# Can't get outer div background to extend to the bottom of the page

Tags: css, html, styling

I am working on this page:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/birds/birds.php

Before the google map, there is a white background.  But after the google map, the original div's white background does not extend lower and the page looks awkward.

Do you know why this is happening and how I can get the white background to extend to the bottom of the page?

Thanks!

Comment: please provide a better description, maybe with screenshots its not completely clear what you want to achieve

Comment: put the map and thing under it inside the <div class="basic">?

Comment: @Trevor but it is already inside basic, isn't it?

Comment: no, you closed the <div> then made a new one for the map under it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the map and thing under it inside the `<div class="basic">`

:)

Answer (score 0):

The html change just didn't show up for me for a little while.  All solved by putting everything inside the div named basic.

Comment: I wish I wrote it as an answer :(